# How to put Column_Name count to the Column names when plotting Heatmap in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Suppose i have more than 100 columns into a dataset.

I want to put the Column_Names count along with the cloumn names(i.e. xticklabels) while displaying the heatmap as it is difficult to understand that the Heatmap is displaying all the columns or not.

I want to plot Column_Names count on the X-axis of heatmap to see that how many columns are getting displayed into the heatmap.

currently i'm using this code to plot heatmap:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
sns.heatmap(df_test.isnull(), yticklabels =False)
```

which gives output:

[CLICK to see the real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUR2i.png)

[Click to see Expected output sample marked with index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb3LE.png)

Comment: Do you want each column name to have a count number like some_name_2, some_other_name_2 or do you want a x axis label that includes the number of columns like This Axe (100)?

Comment: i want just to identify each columns with a number as it's index so that i can know that if my dataset is having 200 columns then all the 200 columns are coming into the heatmap or not... it can be like column_name_1 or column_name_2 or Column_name_3 or it can be indexed like i've marked into the pic which i've now attached into the post.